# How can I access a specific spreadsheet cell (from a list of them) using a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's the situation: I have a list of numbers in a spreadsheet, all in a column. In another part of the spreadsheet, I'd like to refer back to the list, and get the value of a particular cell, based on a formula.

As an example: the list is from A1 down to A50.  In another part of the spreadsheet, at C100 I would like to access a particular cell, based on the formula.  Suppose it is A(5*5), which corresponds to A25. These formulas change depending on the cell I want to place the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this and sub the real formula you want for 5*5.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5*5, 1))
```